# How to use libuv with a bytecode virtual machine

Tags: c, asynchronous, bytecode, event-loop, libuv

How would you use libuv inside a bytecode virtual machine, say i have this function

```c
void vm_run(vm_t* vm);
```

Which starts the virtual machine to execute code it will keep running as long the user's code does so, now i want to add asynchronous stuff in the language VM say a `setTimeout`/`setInterval` like JavaScript, i can expose the native function to the user but when to actually start the event loop, `uv_run` blocks until there's no events left and the VM also blocks until the user's code ends how would i start both together in order to keep the VM doing async I/O, I'm just struggling to understand the idea of an event loop properly in such a context, someone please guide me to the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way, you have to run the uv event loop when the normal execution ends to process events, so i have to make an API to run functions in the VM at anytime (in other words return from vm_run does not mean all code is done we will execute more functions further)